.NET 8 Grpc failed to connect over HTTP/2
I have migrated our api server from .net core 7 to .net core 8 and after that HTTP/2 stopped working.
I have tried the following configuration which is working fine at .net core 7. My application runs in Kubernetes, and I set those environment variables.
- name: ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Endpoints__Grpc__Url           
  value: http://*:5762         
- name: ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Endpoints__Grpc__Protocols           
  value: Http2         
- name: ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Endpoints__Http__Url           
  value: http://*:80         
- name: ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Endpoints__Http__Protocols           
  value: Http1         
- name: ASPNETCORE_URLS           
  value: http://+:80;http://+:5762

For .net core 8 I have set this also
- name: ASPNETCORE_HTTP_PORTS           
  value: "80;5762"

But from client it's redirect to http/1.1
Exception Info: Grpc.Core.RpcException: Status(StatusCode="Internal", Detail="Request protocol 'HTTP/1.1' is not supported.")
In .net core 8 default port is changed.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/containers/8.0/aspnet-port
Could someone please point out which configuration I am missing.
Thanks in advance.
Edit:

Above configuration is correct. We had routing problem in Kubernetes.
I discover that after post this question.

Thanks Everyone.

Net 8 still has lots of issues.  HTTP 1.1 is stream mode and closes after each HTTP Request/Response.  HTTP/2 The stream remain open until close so you can make more than one request/response on a connection.  So I'm not sure why HTTP/1.1 is being called.  Did you do a clean build after changing from Net 7.0 to Net 8.0?  GRPC may be doing a retry when HTTP/2 fails it then tries HTTP/1.1.  In Net 7.0 the connection completed, In Net 8.0 connection is failing and then retrying HTTP/1.1.   Real issue is a HTTP/2 is failing in Net 8 and not Net 7.
